# App is not running in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, ios-frameworks

My app is running without any error in device. But while running in simulator so many link errors occuring.
[image: Link Errors]

Here is code for Google Add view (banner view)

```
-(void)loadAddMobConfigs{

switch ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom) {
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone:
        self.bannerSizes = @[ @"Large Banner", @"Banner", @"Smart Banner" ];
        break;
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad:
        self.bannerSizes = @[
                             @"Large Banner", @"Banner", @"Smart Banner",
                             @"Full Banner",
                             @"Medium Rectangle",
                             @"Leaderboard"
                             ];
        break;
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiomUnspecified:
        self.bannerSizes = @[ @"Large Banner", @"Banner", @"Smart Banner" ];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

self.ads = @{
             @"Banner" : NSValueFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner),
             @"Large Banner" : NSValueFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeLargeBanner),
             @"Smart Banner Portrait" : NSValueFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait),
             @"Smart Banner Landscape" : NSValueFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape),
             @"Full Banner" : NSValueFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeFullBanner),
             @"Medium Rectangle" : NSValueFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle),
             @"Leaderboard" : NSValueFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeLeaderboard)
             };

if (!self.bannerView)
{
    self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] init];
    self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    self.bannerView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
}
```

}

Am using Banner ads

Comment: Is it running on a real device?

Comment: Yes it is running.

Comment: Please share your code for Google Add view (banner view) also let us know, have you used native ads or banner ads?

Comment: May be your app is related to device related functionality like Photo capture by camera and You have miss the check for camera availability. Can you provide some information about functionality.

Comment: No i didn't using camera at all @Aashish1aug

Comment: I have also get this issue when implement Google ads sometime it is not working on Simulator but it was working fine on device. I think it's not a issue may be simulator is not supported properly for latest Google Ads.

Comment: @Aashish1aug : I don't think so. I think @Karthikeyan is missing some **frameworks** in his project. Because I faced the same issue when I added the latest `GoogleMaps frameworks` manually. I forgot to add some frameworks which is mentioned in their documentation. Finally when I added those frameworks the errors were gone. I suggest @Karthikeyan to check `GoogleAds` documentation and add those missing frameworks.

Comment: @Aashish1aug but my app is running perfectly in real devices without any framework issues

Comment: You have to cross check once again the Google ads related framework as Suggested by @Poles .